# CSS li list, margin from the left

Tags: html, css, margin

I don`t understand why I have margin from the left:

[image: example]

CSS:

```
html, body {
    font-family:Myriad Pro, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: url('./images/background.png');
}

#container {
    width:890px;
    height:530px;
    margin:36px auto;
}

#userList {
    width:228px;
    height:355px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
}

.users li {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="userList"><ul class="users"><li><img src="./pic/none.png">Piet van Meerdijk</li><li><img src="./pic/none.png">Henk v/d Wal</li></ul></div>
```

When I put margin-left:-40px; in the CSS code the li item will be on the left now, but then have I a margin on the right. Why?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cwcy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<ul>` tag has an automatic `padding` of `40px` so you will need to change that to 0px:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This should work across all browsers.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cwcy/3/

Comment: Works in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox, IE etc. Is there a fix that works in every browser?

Answer (score 0):

By default a lot of HTML elements have their own CSS rules in many browsers, and `<ul>` tag has a padding by default. You need to set padding:0px to de `<ul>` tag:

```
ul{
padding:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cwcy/1/

If you want to know more about CSS reset rules follow [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) link.